# install ubuntu (11.10 or above) on dell xps 17 - dual booting

Tags: windows-7, dell, xps

Some time ago I briefly looked into installing Ubuntu 11.10 (or above) on my dell xps17. I remember there were quite a few issues (sorry can't remember which ones, it was long time ago) and I was wondering if anybody could let me know if I can install it without having any problems at all (I would like to keep windows 7 there anyway).

My processor is Intel(r) Core(tm) i7-2720QM 2.2ghz.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Dell with a i5 2320 (Sandy Bridge) and have had no problems with 12.04.  Before that I had both 11.04 and 11.10 installed on my old Dell 2.8Ghz Dual core built in about 2004 and had no problems with either of those so I'm not sure what problems you saw.

In 12.04 I would suggest:

Installing `mesa-utils` will improve the display(mine was slightly too large for the screen without it)

Installing `libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0` will provide the texture compression library needed for `mesa` to display some of the better games(Note: some games that need the s3tc compression will not load as they think that the card does not support it(Psyconauts is one) and must be forced in the terminal with `force_s3tc_enable=true (program)` (even with that my GPU will not run Psyconauts but will force enable others)

Those are the only things I can think of so you should be fine installing 12.04 on your computer.

Note: if you have a non-integrated GPU(AMD,Nvidia, ATI) you will need to install the proprietary drivers for those and there are plenty of answers here on askubuntu.  I will defer to those as I don't have any and have never had to install them.  From what I have seen in passing, hybrid graphic cards require some work to get working if they work at all, but again I cannot verify any of those problems myself.

Comment: hi thanks, I have an Nvidia geforce gt 555m so will have a look. Problem is I have read in a few places that people had loads of probs with ubuntu on the xp17

Comment: @user76434 If you really want try Ubuntu and want to know if it works with your system. Before committing to a dual boot, why not install via Wubi(the Windows installer).  That way if it doesn't work you can uninstall it like any other Windows program and nothing will be lost.  If you want to try this, make sure you follow the directions on installing the Nvidia drivers before deciding if it works. Wubi works by installing a virtual disk as a file within windows so you will get slightly degraded performance but it will let you know yes or no for sure. Then you can go dual boot if it works.

Answer (score 0):

> ...I was wondering if anybody could let me know if I can install it
>   without having any problems at all...

Hi, if you want to know how to install Ubuntu in a dual boot configuration and you have never done it before, let me tell you it is a very simple and straightforward process. I found [this](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/10/27/dual-boot-ubuntu-11-10-windows-7-on-a-pc-with-2-hard-drives/) graphical tutorial very easy to understand and hope it can answer your question in the best possible way.

In regards to the "... without having any problems at all", I don't see why you should have any, however, as with any other major system modification, **you should always backup before installation**, it's a best practice and won't leave you without your precious information in case anything goes wrong.

And last but not least, if you actually find any issues in your way [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), there is always an answer...

Comment: hi thanks, I have an Nvidia geforce gt 555m so will have a look. Problem is I have read in a few places that people had loads of probs with ubuntu on the xp17 – user76434 just now edit

Answer (score 0):

I have a dell Studio xps 17 as well,

On 10.04 i had issues qith the video card, on 12.04 it seems to be fixed.
The only thing i had to 'tweak' was my headphone jacks. Both works now.

If you need to patch your headphone jacks, this worked for me:
Open alsa-base.conf:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

add this line at the end of the file (last line)

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m6
```

Beside that's everything is smooth on 12.04.